# For a non-constant entire function which property is possible?

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers

Let $f$ be a non-constant entire function.Which of the following properties is possible for each $z \in \mathbb{C}$

$(1) \  \ \mathrm{Re} f(z) =\mathrm{Im} f(z)$

$(2) \ \ |f(z)|<1$

$(3)\ \ \mathrm{Im} f(z)<0$

$(4)\ \  f(z) \neq 0 $

I tried for $(2)$ and $(3)$ option.For $(2) f$ is entire and bounded by Louiville's theorem it has to be constant which is contradiction to hypothesis.for $(3)$ if imaginary part or real part is bounded below or above then function has to be constant.How eliminate $(1)$ & $(4)$? I don't know what are the right option.

**Here it is possible that there are more than one answers**. Please help me thanks in advance.

Comment: Think of the non-constant entire functions you know.  Which of the above properties do they satisfy?

Comment: I suppose first thing you should have tried for first case is cauchy riemann... you tried that?

Answer (score 4):

$f(z)=u(x,y)+iu(x,y)$

$u_x=u_y$ and $u_y=-u_x$

Can you conclude now?

Comment: In the first option it can't be hold.

Comment: so... what do you want to say?

Comment: So,first is not true.

Comment: How to prove last option by assuming $f(z)=0$ for some $z$ in $\mathbb{C}$ and function is given entire Can i prove that function is zero on complex plane.

Comment: Thanks Cameron Buie and Praphulla Koushik both of you.

Answer (score 4):

**1.** Consider the function , $g(z)=e^{f^2(z)}$. Then , $g$ is entire (as $f$ is). Now , $$|g(z)|=\left|e^{(u^2-v^2)+2iuv}\right|=e^{u^2-v^2}=1.$$where , $f=u+iv$ and given $u=v$. So , $g$ is entire and bounded and hence constant. So , $f$ is constant ,which contradicts. So , it is **FALSE**.

**2.** Clearly $f$ is bounded and entire and hence constant. So , it is **FALSE**.

**3.** Consider , $g(z)=e^{-if(z)}$. Then $g$ is bounded and entire and hence constant and so $f$ is constant. So , it is **FALSE**.

So, only **4.** is **TRUE**.

Answer (score 3):

**Hints**: For $1,$ note that $f$ can't be $0$ everywhere, nor can its derivative. Hence, there is some non-empty open set that $f$ maps to an open set. (Why?) Can the line $\operatorname{Re}(w)=\operatorname{Im}(w)$ contain any non-empty open set?

For $4,$ try to think of an example of a non-constant entire function that is *never* $0.$ (A basic example should do.)

Comment: If I consider $f(z)=e^z$ then $(4)$ holds and there are many entire function.

Comment: Bingo! That tells you that $4$ is a possibility. All that's left is for you to rule out option $1.$ You can proceed in the way I mentioned, or alternately, you can use the Cauchy-Riemann equations.

Comment: Can i prove last one? If I amssuming $f(z)=0$ for some $z$ and function is entire then can i prove fuction is zero everywhere?

Comment: You have *already* proven the last one. $f(z)=e^z$ is a nonconstant entire function such that $f(z)\ne0$ for all $z.$ Thus, it is possible for a nonconstant entire function to be nonzero everywhere. Proof by example complete.

Comment: You cannot prove that if an entire function has a zero, then it is zero everywhere, since it isn't true. Think of some other basic examples of entire functions to see this.

Comment: Ok. It means it is not true always.

Comment: Thanks Cameron Buie and Praphulla Koushik both of you.

Comment: True. An entire function may be zero everywhere, nowhere, or on any discrete subset of the plane (that is, a subset that has no limit points in the plane). A *nonconstant* entire function is either zero nowhere or on some discrete subset of the plane. You are very welcome.